# Insert query in DB from checkbox count

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in my HTML page. When a user chose for example six checkboxes, I want to save it into a database like 1 for the first checkbox, 2 for the second .... and 6 for the last checked:

```
foreach ($tape as $tap) {
    //some variables
    // I have tried this but it gives me 1 everytime. 
    $i = 1;
    $i = sprintf('%02d', $i);
    $array = array($the_date, $i);
    $ref = implode(".Tape.", $array); // for 2016_73_98.Tape.01

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO test (server, tape, 'date', reference, tape_name) 
         VALUES (:server, :tape, :the_date, :reference, :tape_name)"
    );
    $stmt->bindParam(':server', $server);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape', $tap);
    $stmt->bindParam(':the_date', $the_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reference', $my_tape);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape_name', $ref);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $i++;
}
```

I tried a for loop with the `$count` which counts how many checked elements, but it inserts 6 times the same choice for each of the 6 inputs.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a34yx.png)

I want to replace in the "tape_name" column, 01 with (01 for the first MA0001, 02 for MA0002 .... ) It doesn’t have anything to do with the reference, it has to be following the number of checked checkboxes.

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++): //adjust this number to whatever number of checkboxes you want
    echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';
    echo '<label for="checkbox' . $i . '">' . $i . '</label>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox' . $i . '" value="' . $i . '"/>';

    echo '</div>';

endfor;
?>
```

Comment: How do you want to store checked values into table? If user selects first three checkboxes then you want to store 1, 2, 3 into table? like that? Or you want to insert three different records/rows, each for selected value?

Comment: so I have that "tape_name" which is the checked checkbox from the form, for example X1, and I have the "$ref" which should be saved as Tape 1/2/3.../7 (lets say 7 is max). When i choose tape X43, X55, X76, i want it to get in the DB as Tape 01 for X43, Tape 02 for X55, Tape 03 for X76. is it clear or should I be more explicit ? basically I want to use the "count" meaning the number of the checked boxes, to then store it in an indep column. PS : I added a picture to my post

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: As per whatever I understood about your query. Just put `$i = 1;` before `foreach` loop, then it will increment properly.

Comment: yes thank you, I missed on that one, it should be put before. But now I need to make sure the first selected item is the one that gets the tape 01 .. now the order of selected elements is not respected... how can I do that ?

Comment: Oh, You mean to say, if you have selected 5th checkbox and 10th checkbox only, then the 5th selected checkbox will get tape 01 and 10th selected checkbox will get tape 02. Am I right?

Comment: I've added answer for two scenarios, let me know if you are looking for something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to use `$i` incrementation here, because you are already storing the incremented number in the checkboxes.

You need to just fetch the selected checkbox value like this.

```
foreach ($tape as $tap) {
    //some variables
    // I have tried this but it gives me 1 everytime. 
    $i = sprintf('%02d', $tap);
    $array = array($the_date, $i);
    $ref = implode(".Tape.", $array); // for 2016_73_98.Tape.01

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO test (server, tape, 'date', reference, tape_name) 
             VALUES (:server, :tape, :the_date, :reference, :tape_name)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':server', $server);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape', $tap);
    $stmt->bindParam(':the_date', $the_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reference', $my_tape);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape_name', $ref);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

**Edited**

Now if you have selected 5th checkbox and 10th checkbox only, then the 5th selected checkbox will get tape 01 and 10th selected checkbox will get tape 02. In that scenario following code will useful

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($tape as $tap) {
    //some variables
    // I have tried this but it gives me 1 everytime. 
    $i = sprintf('%02d', $i);
    $array = array($the_date, $i);
    $ref = implode(".Tape.", $array); // for 2016_73_98.Tape.01

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO test (server, tape, 'date', reference, tape_name) 
             VALUES (:server, :tape, :the_date, :reference, :tape_name)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':server', $server);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape', $tap);
    $stmt->bindParam(':the_date', $the_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reference', $my_tape);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape_name', $ref);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $i++;
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

---

**Edited after understanding further requirement**

Add following jquery code in your script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){

       var cnt = Number($("#store_count").val());

        var checked_index = $(this).val(); alert("checked_index:" + checked_index);

        if($(this).is(":checked")){

            $(this).val(cnt); $("#store_count").val(cnt + 1);
        }
        else{

            $(this).val("");

            $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){

                if( $(this).val() > checked_index ){ $(this).val(Number($(this).val()) - 1); }
            });

            $("#store_count").val(cnt - 1);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

then make following changes in your HTML code, we need one hidden field to keep track of the counter.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++): //adjust this number to whatever number of checkboxes you want

    echo '<div class="each_checkboxes">';
    echo '<label for="checkbox' . $i . '">' . $i . '</label>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tape[]" id="checkbox' . $i . '" value=""/>';
    echo '</div>';

endfor;

echo '<input type="hidden" id="store_count" value="1" />';
?>
```

And finally your inserting data into database code

You don't even need to use $i incrementation here, because you are already storing the incremented number in the checkboxes.

You need to just fetch the selected checkbox value like this.

```
foreach ($tape as $tap) {
    //some variables
    // I have tried this but it gives me 1 everytime. 
    $i = sprintf('%02d', $tap);
    $array = array($the_date, $i);
    $ref = implode(".Tape.", $array); // for 2016_73_98.Tape.01

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO test (server, tape, 'date', reference, tape_name) 
             VALUES (:server, :tape, :the_date, :reference, :tape_name)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':server', $server);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape', $tap);
    $stmt->bindParam(':the_date', $the_date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reference', $my_tape);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tape_name', $ref);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Indeed the code is working, but it still doesn't put the 01 in the first selected checkbox : when I chose 45, 8, 14, in this order, i got tape01 for the 8, though I want it to be in 45, the first checked

Comment: In that case you have to you jquery, because PHP doesn't which checkbox you selected first and which second.

Comment: oh okey thank you very much ! Can you orient me to which property I shall use in jQuery ? Thanks again mate !

Comment: In that case I've one question. If user has selected 45, 8 and then 14. So as per your requirement 45 will get 01, 8 will get 02 and 14 will get 03. Now what happens if user uncheck 45 and check 35?

Comment: then 35 (old 45) is the last selected one (8 will become first)

Comment: No what happens to the order? if 45 is no more 1st selected? 8 will become 1st and 14th will become 2nd like that?

Comment: exactly ! 8 first, 14 second, 35 (any other new) will be last

Comment: @Xibition Look I've added my answer at the end, please check and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Please accept and up-vote my answer ;)